# Is it safe to lift up your wipers in cold weather?

Tags: windshield-wipers

Lifting up your wipers prevent them from sticking to the windshield in freezing weather. However, is it safe to do so? I'm concerned the wipers might get frozen / stuck while they are upright, causing even more problems.